# Is Entity Framework available for Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-express

I want to use Entity Framework for my data access on a project I'm writing in Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.

Can it be done?  What do I need to know?

**Update**: My question has been answered, so thanks.  As a followup, can you use a visual design tool or are you stuck with the EdmGen.exe command line tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using EF in Visual Web Developer 2008 Express, so I'm *guessing* that yes, it will also be available in Visual C# Express.

Comment: I've looked into it some more, and yes, you're right - it is available.  One question, do you use the commandline EdmGen tool?  Do you know of any visual design tools like the ones you get with the .Net 3.5 SP1 download?

Comment: It does come with a visual edmx designer complete with entity designer and mapping.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) it comes as standard

> Create data-enabled applications
>   with the lightweight SQL Server
>   Compact Edition or powerful
>   client/serve applications with  SQL
>   Server 2008 Express
>
> - Build applications using LINQ (Language Integrated Query) which adds
>     data querying capabilities for SQL
>     Server, XML, and objects to Visual C#
> - Support for the Entity Framework and designer tool